# Python Flask server on elastic beanstalk cant save files

Tags: python, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to upload and save a file to my EC2 instance so that I can do some file manipulation.

My upload looks like this:

```py
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.getcwd() + '/uploads'
application = Flask(__name__)
CORS(application)
application.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

@application.route("/test-upload", methods=["POST"])
def test_upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save(os.path.join(application.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    # return redirect(url_for('download_file', name=filename))
    return str(os.path.join(application.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
```

If I remove the `file.save()` line, then the function won't return errors. And as you can see I'm returning the path, so that will return the correct path. But, I get a 500 bad request from the server when I try and save the file.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

I can locally try this using postman, and this works fine. The file saves to the right location. I do have file size for EC2 enabled to be 100MB, but I am testing with a 50 Byte file so size can't be the issue. I know the file is being uploaded to the EC2 web server for sure.

Comment: Do you have access to the error logs? There may be information there. Likely a permission / location issue.

Comment: under elastic beanstalk > logs, if I download the last 100 lines the error section is blank

Comment: please check under /var/log/httpd/error.log

Comment: If you see anything like "wb" permission error, make sure that the all the folders have 755 and all the files have 644 permission. You can change this with chmod.
If the error persists, find out which user is running your python API and make sure that the folder is owned by the same user (use ls -la to check and chown to change owner). 
If it still doesnt work, post output of /var/log/httpd/error.log as we are not psychic.

Comment: there is no /var/log/httpd/error.log file, the only file there is health

Comment: I noticed the uploads folder wasn't there when I was digging around on the ec2 instance. It seems that if a folder is empty, ec2 will delete it. That seems odd to me, but adding a temp file seems to keep the folder and then file.save works!

Comment: At what time does ec2 delete the folder? If you are using git, any empty folders are not committed, so the source code won't contain the folder. Even then, it's better to check if the directory exists and if not create while setting up the server.